# select distinct a.* from table query

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I'm on a new project and there are a lot of sql server stored procedures in which I'm tasked with working on, improving, fixing etc..

I was surprised to see code like this:

```
select distinct a.*  from tbl_applicant a
```

1. When would this code work?
2. If it did work on some tables, it is masking proper results?
3. What should be used instead?

Comment: Is that the complete query or is it joining on another table? Does `tbl_applicant` have a primary key?

Comment: good question, I need to check the actual code when I get to work

Comment: In the query as shown, the distinct is totally useless. The column list will include the primary key column(s) and therefor no duplicates can be part of the resulset that would be "removed" by the `distinct` operator.

Comment: That is what I figured.  I was a little rusty with sql and didn't see a query like this in many years so I wanted to ask

Comment: Do Distincts in general cause a performance hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If table `tbl_applicant` exists
2. No, it's only eliminate dupliacte rows.
3. `select col1,col2 ... from tbl_applicant group by col1,col2 ...` or with alias `a`
   `select a.col1, a.col2 ... from tbl_applicant a group by a.col1,a.col2 ...`

Comment: Parado, is there an advantage for GroupBy rather then Distinct
(leave aside the fact that you can use Agregation for GroupBy)
i mean performance side

Comment: @TomerW - Not in this case no and the disadvantage is the need to list all columns in the `group by`

Answer (score 1):

1> As already mentioned, this query will work if the table tbl_applicant exists.

2> 'a' in the query is just an alias for the table name 'tbl_applicant'. In your case a.* is the same as *. a.* doesn't mask / change anything on the result.

"*" itself will select all columns of the table. Whether this is OK depends on your system. Often it's better to use explicit column names (e.g. a.col1, a.col2,...). In this case, you can add additonal columns to the database, but your applications won't see these columns. In addition, you get a well defined ordering of columns in your code.

'distinct' is used to remove duplicates. If you remove distinct, then you may get a different value. What you really get depends on the data in your table. If you have for example a primary key in your table, then it's impossible to have duplicate rows and distinct is not required. distinct is not for free. Removing duplicates will cost you some runtime. You should use distinct only, if you really need it.

3> If you have to remove duplicate rows and if you always need all columns, then your statement is OK.

Answer (score 0):

1. It works.
2. Can be.
3. This:

   `SELECT distinct * FROM TESTTABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing is used to select only columns from chosen table. Normaly it's used with joins e.g.:

```
SELECT u.*, p.name
FROM user u
JOIN product p ON u.Id = p.productID
```

you'll get all columns from user table and only product name. In your example it's used separately, it's not a mistake, but SELECT DISTINCT * FROM... will work too. 
You can read more on [Table Aliasing on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)